# ERROR: when start hadoop

Tags: ssh, 14.04, localhost, hadoop

I am installed Hadoop, following [Michael noll](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)'s tutorial. When I start name node using as following command,

```
hduser@ARUL-PC:/usr/local/hadoop$ sbin/start-all.sh
```

I got response as,

```
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
14/05/03 12:36:43 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
localhost]
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'
-c: Unknown cipher type 'cd'
64-Bit: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 64-bit: Name or service not known
Server: ssh: Could not resolve hostname server: Name or service not known
recommended: ssh: Could not resolve hostname recommended: Name or service not known
hduser@localhost's password: link: ssh: Could not resolve hostname link: No address associated with hostname
OpenJDK: ssh: Could not resolve hostname openjdk: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
now.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname now.: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname vm: Name or service not known
guard: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard: Name or service not known
loaded: ssh: Could not resolve hostname loaded: Name or service not known
that: ssh: Could not resolve hostname that: Name or service not known
The: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
or: ssh: Could not resolve hostname or: Name or service not known
library: ssh: Could not resolve hostname library: Name or service not known
<libfile>',: ssh: Could not resolve hostname <libfile>',: Name or service not known
'-z: ssh: Could not resolve hostname '-z: Name or service not known
with: ssh: Could not resolve hostname with: Name or service not known
noexecstack'.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname noexecstack'.: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
to: ssh: Could not resolve hostname to: Name or service not known
the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
will: ssh: Could not resolve hostname will: Name or service not known
it: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it: Name or service not known
the: ssh: Could not resolve hostname the: Name or service not known
which: ssh: Could not resolve hostname which: Name or service not known
guard.: ssh: Could not resolve hostname guard.: Name or service not known
disabled: ssh: Could not resolve hostname disabled: Name or service not known
might: ssh: Could not resolve hostname might: Name or service not known
VM: ssh: Could not resolve hostname vm: Name or service not known
stack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname stack: Name or service not known
You: ssh: Could not resolve hostname you: Name or service not known
you: ssh: Could not resolve hostname you: Name or service not known
It's: ssh: Could not resolve hostname it's: Name or service not known
highly: ssh: Could not resolve hostname highly: Name or service not known
'execstack: ssh: Could not resolve hostname 'execstack: Name or service not known
have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known
try: ssh: Could not resolve hostname try: Name or service not known
fix: ssh: Could not resolve hostname fix: Name or service not known
warning:: ssh: Could not resolve hostname warning:: Name or service not known
```

Please tell me where I did mistake...

When I check configuration folder I saw the below,

```
root@ARUL-PC:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop# ls
capacity-scheduler.xml  hadoop-metrics2.properties  httpfs-site.xml             ssl-client.xml.example
configuration.xsl       hadoop-metrics.properties   log4j.properties            ssl-server.xml.example
container-executor.cfg  hadoop-policy.xml           mapred-env.cmd              yarn-env.cmd
core-site.xml           hdfs-site.xml               mapred-env.sh               yarn-env.sh
core-site.xml~          hdfs-site.xml~              mapred-queues.xml.template  yarn-site.xml
hadoop-env.cmd          httpfs-env.sh               mapred-site.xml.template
hadoop-env.sh           httpfs-log4j.properties     mapred-site.xml.template~
hadoop-env.sh~          httpfs-signature.secret     slaves
```

that I added lines as per [tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) said in hadoop-env.sh, core-site.xml, for that files another files has automatically created ending with '~' as same as file name. Is it normal or it's an problem?

I open that file using 'gedit' as,

```
root@ARUL-PC:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop# gedit hadoop-env.sh~
```

I can see,

[image: Image:: hadoop-env.sh~]

How to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As for files ending with ~:
gedit creates backup on saving file named ~. If you dont want this behavior, you can disable it in Preferences -> Editor -> Create copy before saving

Comment: k thank you.. so that's not my problem.. then can you tell me where I did mistake ?

Answer (score -1):

tutorial was set with hadoop 1.x and your environment is set with hadoop 2.x ... the JobTracker/TaskTracker of 1.x is different on 2.x; JobTracker is split into ResourceManager and AppManager, and each data node now has a NodeManager ... not sure if the task-tracker of 1.x is part of 2.x NodeManager...
an updated 2.x (I used 2.5.0) hadoop install tutorial would help, this one helped: http://www.alexjf.net/blog/distributed-systems/hadoop-yarn-installation-definitive-guide/#Introduction 
YARN is the 2.x addition that replaced the JobTracker, etc.